# Number of ways to split a set into non-empty subsets where no subset includes another

Tags: combinatorics

I am looking to find the number of not necessarily disjoint partitions of a set into non-empty subsets. No member of a partition should be a subset of another member.

For example, let $ A:=\lbrace 1, 2, 3 \rbrace $ be the set to be decomposed. Then the partitions are:

1. $\lbrace 1, 2, 3 \rbrace$
2. $\lbrace 1, 2 \rbrace, \lbrace 3 \rbrace$
3. $\lbrace 1, 3 \rbrace, \lbrace 2 \rbrace$
4. $\lbrace 2, 3 \rbrace, \lbrace 1 \rbrace$
5. $\lbrace 1, 2 \rbrace, \lbrace 1, 3 \rbrace$
6. $\lbrace 1, 2 \rbrace, \lbrace 2, 3 \rbrace$
7. $\lbrace 1, 3 \rbrace, \lbrace 2, 3 \rbrace$
8. $\lbrace 1, 2 \rbrace, \lbrace 1, 3 \rbrace , \lbrace 2, 3 \rbrace$
9. $\lbrace 1 \rbrace, \lbrace 2 \rbrace, \lbrace 3 \rbrace$

In the case of $\vert A \vert = 3$, the number is 9 (hoping that I did not forget any). What is the general result for $\vert A \vert = n$?

---

**Update:** I added $\lbrace 1, 2 \rbrace, \lbrace 1, 3 \rbrace , \lbrace 2, 3 \rbrace$ to the original question as I had forgotten it. I was not aware of the correct terminology, I will read up on it.

Comment: "Partition" means something else - specifically disjoint. (An element of a partition is called a part.) You seem to want an anti-chain that covers the whole set.

Comment: Why not $\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\}?$ Does if have to be minimal - that is, excluding one part will no longer contain all the elements?

Comment: Following to @Thomas Andrews comment, you are looking for OEIS [A006126](https://oeis.org/A006126).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Thomas Andrews and BillyJoe for pointing out that this problem is the "number of antichain covers of a labeled n-set" and more information can be found at https://oeis.org/A006126 .